# IE 8 submit button styles do not work

Tags: html, css, button

I have this form: http://www.problemio.com/add_problem.php

and the button at the bottom has some css styles which render on all browsers except IE it seems.

Here is my css for the style of the button:

```
.button
{
  -moz-border-radius:3px;
  -webkit-border-radius:3px;
  border-radius: 3x;
  border: 1px solid #ABABAB;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#E1E1E1), to(#F7F7F7));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E1E1E1, #F7F7F7);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E1E1E1, #F7F7F7);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E1E1E1, #F7F7F7);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #E1E1E1, #F7F7F7);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #E1E1E1, #F7F7F7);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#E1E1E1', EndColorStr='#F7F7F7');
  padding: 6px;

  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: 100% "League Gothic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Comment: What happens in IE9?  Just the default button style?

Comment: @JamesMontagne sorry I typoed originally and the error is from IE 8. The issue is that the styles I gave that .button class don't all render, but some render.

Comment: Aside from the pointy corners it looks okay to me.

Comment: @JamesMontagne yeah its a bit weird, its like it picks up some styles, but not all.  I also added these background: #ffce2e; color: #444; but they do not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `p` on `border-radius: 3px`.

Comment: I'm getting used to people using vendor extensions and typoing the one IE uses, then blaming IE for "being a crap browser"...

Comment: Unfortunately I just tried it with the fix, and it didn't fix the styling problems :(

Comment: It is working, however `filters` are not programmed to cooperate with `border-radius` (because at the time they were not co-existant). Therefore, even if you set the `border-radius` to a large amount, the gradient background will still be rectangular.